# Delete Secure Store Services master key?

Tags: performancepoint, secure-store

Please bear with me, I'm new to Sharepoint / Performancepoint.
I am working on a local share point server that is only used to test sites before creating them on the live server.

I need to create a PerformancePoint dashboard, however it complains that I need to refresh the Master Key. When I go to manage the Secure Store Services, I get the error message 'Unable to obtain master key.'

When I try to generate a key, I receive the error

"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.KeyManagement.InvalidMasterKeyException' was thrown."

I can not refresh the key either since nobody knows what the original passphrase was.
If it can not be deleted, is there some work around?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the SecureStore application and re-create it.

Be careful though, as you'll have to recreate all the entries for other applications, like Excel Services (if there are any that is).

Comment: Hi James,
What do you mean by other entries? It seems our secure store db may be corrupt so we want to delete and recreate the application. But we want to understand the implications of deleting. Can you help us?

Comment: All the Target Application entries that applications use, like maybe Excel Services, PerformancePoint Services, or other accounts stored in there, will have to be deleted. You'll have to check against your farm configuration documentation to see what was created.